# Images in carousel flicker

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created the following images carousel that appears only on mobile:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <img class="second"  src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/transimage.png">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/3-1.jpg" alt="tempo">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/6-3.jpg" alt="snickers">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/23.jpg" alt="wizz">
                              <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/35-1.jpg" alt="הוואי"> 

                 <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/NesherPointer.jpg" alt="נשר">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/2.jpg" alt="Xerox">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/9.jpg" alt="Neutrogena">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/8.jpg" alt="Orbit">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/11.jpg" alt="M & M">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/12.jpg" alt="Mercedes-Benz">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/15-1.jpg" alt="Hyundai">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/14.jpg" alt="Johnnson & Johnson">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/16-1.jpg" alt="Decathlon">

         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/22-1.jpg" alt="תעבורה">

         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/UPSPEPSI.jpg" alt="Pepsi & UPS">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/27-1.jpg" alt="Mars">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/fivebabysitter.jpg" alt="5 & babysitter">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/mastercardnetflix.jpg" alt="Mastercard & netflix">
                  <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/19-1.jpg" alt="Bang & Olufsen">

         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/25-1.jpg" alt="Newpan">

         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/28-1.jpg" alt="Magimix">
         <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/29-1.jpg" alt="LR Group">
                  <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/30-1.jpg" alt="Colombil Corp">
                  <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/31-1.jpg" alt="Kitchen Aid">
                                    <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/32-1.jpg" alt="הוואי">       <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/33-1.jpg" alt="Haier">
                                                                                      <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/34-1.jpg" alt="DeLonghi">


          </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/* Photo Banner */
.container {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background: white;
}

.photobanner {
    height: 120px;
    width: 3000px;
}

.photobanner img {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}

.photobanner img  {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}


/*keyframe animations*/
.second {
    -webkit-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;;
}

@keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: 200px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermoves {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 120% {margin-left: 200px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -100px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: 200px;}

@-o-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: 200px;}
}
```

The problem is that when I view it on mobile the images flicker/shake a bit and I can't figure out why. You can see it for yourself on www.wolfppr.donut.co.il (Scroll down a bit on the homepage, you will see a carousel of logos).[wolfppr.donut.co.il](http://www.wolfppr.donut.co.il) There's another carousel for desktops, but it's unrelated to the mobile carousel.
I have no idea why it's happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using margins or positions for animations/transitions in CSS will almost always result in "jerky" or "flickering" motion. Elements only use GPU acceleration when the browser determines it would benefit them. Since Margin shouldn't be used for positioning elements, those elements suffer from frame-rate drops, hence the stuttering.

Take a look at this CodePen, it simply compares a short left/right animation using Margin, Position, and Transform: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/MBmWPm

Instead of

```
@keyframes a {
    from { margin-left: 0; }
    to   { margin-left: calc( 100vw - 30px ); }
}
```

It makes use of

```
@keyframes c {
    from { transform: translateX(0); }
    to   { transform: translateX( calc( 100vw - 30px ) ); }
}
```

Especially on mobile, you'll notice the Transform box is significantly smoother.

Comment: In case of my margins:
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: 200px;}

Should it be {transform:translteX(-3000px); } {transform: translteX( calc(200px)); }

I'm a bit confused

Comment: No worries - you shouldn't actually need `calc` at all, I just used it in a quick pinch to prevent the block sliding off screen. Funny thing about translate is that you can use pixels just fine, but percents will base it off the elements proportions. So in your case you can try `0% { transform: translateX(-3000px); }` and `100% { transform: translateX(200px); }`